# Firestore: Validate array of objects

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking for a solution to validate the following data structure:
An array of objects with the same keys (`propertyA`, `propertyB`) and same type of values (`string`).

```
{
  title: 'Hello World',
  toValidate: [
    {
      propertyA: 'string', // Always the same keys
      propertyB: 'string'  // Always a string
    },
    {
      propertyA: 'string',
      propertyB: 'string'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Wondering this also. Seems like there's no way to check fields data type, since 'typeof ' operator don't exist.

Comment: My bad. To check type there is 'is' operator. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#resource

Answer (score -1):

You are probably looking for subcollections. They can have their own validation rules.

Comment: do you have an example?

Comment: You can find examples of matching sub collections here: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#hierarchical_data

Comment: Then jus use "is string" etc. validation rules as in the link in the above comment.